# Что такое Numpy, и с чем его едят?

Tags: python, numpy, библиотеки

Numpy - это просто модуль, с помощью которого можно быстро создать массив, и памяти тратится меньше, чем  со стандартным питоном и списками?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/whatisnumpy.html

Comment: Стоит ознакомиться с https://numpy.org/

Comment: Или по-русски: NumPy это open-source модуль для python, который предоставляет общие математические и числовые операции в виде пре-скомпилированных, быстрых функций. Они объединяются в высокоуровневые пакеты. Они обеспечивают функционал, который можно сравнить с функционалом MatLab. NumPy (Numeric Python) предоставляет базовые методы для манипуляции с большими массивами и матрицами. SciPy (Scientific Python) расширяет функционал numpy огромной коллекцией полезных алгоритмов, таких как минимизация, преобразование Фурье, регрессия, и другие прикладные математические техники.

Comment: Вы уж начните с "что такое google, и с чем его едят, и как его использовать для поиска ответа на тривиальные вопросы".

Answer (score 4):

[Результат перевода официальной документации при помощи `Google Translate`:](https://translate.google.ru/translate?sl=auto&tl=ru&u=https%3A%2F%2Fnumpy.org%2Fdoc%2Fstable%2Fuser%2Fwhatisnumpy.html)

> **Что такое NumPy?**
>
> NumPy - это фундаментальный пакет для научных вычислений на Python.
> Это библиотека Python, которая предоставляет объект многомерного
> массива, различные производные объекты (такие как замаскированные
> массивы и матрицы) и набор процедур для быстрых операций с массивами,
> включая математические, логические, манипуляции с формами, сортировку,
> выбор, ввод-вывод. , дискретные преобразования Фурье, базовая линейная
> алгебра, базовые статистические операции, случайное моделирование и
> многое другое.
>
> В основе пакета NumPy лежит объект ndarray . Это инкапсулирует n
> -мерные массивы однородных типов данных, при этом многие операции выполняются в скомпилированном коде для повышения производительности.
> Между массивами NumPy и стандартными последовательностями Python есть
> несколько важных отличий:
>
> Массивы NumPy имеют фиксированный размер при создании, в отличие от
> списков Python (которые могут расти динамически). Изменение размера
> ndarray создаст новый массив и удалит оригинал.
>
> Все элементы в массиве NumPy должны иметь один и тот же тип данных и,
> следовательно, будут иметь одинаковый размер в памяти. Исключение:
> можно иметь массивы объектов (Python, включая NumPy), что позволяет
> создавать массивы элементов разного размера.
>
> Массивы NumPy упрощают сложные математические и другие типы операций с
> большим количеством данных. Как правило, такие операции выполняются
> более эффективно и с меньшим количеством кода, чем это возможно при
> использовании встроенных последовательностей Python.
>
> Растущее множество научных и математических пакетов на основе Python
> используют массивы NumPy; хотя они обычно поддерживают ввод
> последовательности Python, они преобразуют такой ввод в массивы NumPy
> перед обработкой и часто выводят массивы NumPy. Другими словами, чтобы
> эффективно использовать большую часть (возможно, даже большую часть)
> современного научного / математического программного обеспечения на
> основе Python, недостаточно просто знать, как использовать встроенные
> типы последовательностей Python - также необходимо знать, как
> использовать массивы NumPy.